# how to convert query related to calculate work hours in MySQL to MS Access

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I want to calculate work hours in each day using MS Access.I have query for same thing in MySQL but this thing is not working in MS Access using pdo PHP.

```
  SELECT MachineNo, Empcardno, Date, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(tsecs)) AS total_time
FROM (
  SELECT CASE WHEN MachineNo = @mn AND Empcardno = @en AND `Date` = @dt
              THEN @rn := @rn + 1
              ELSE @rn := 1
         END AS rn,
         @mn := MachineNo AS MachineNo, @en := Empcardno AS Empcardno, 
         @dt := `Date` AS `Date`,
         CASE WHEN @rn % 2 = 1 THEN -TIME_TO_SEC(`Time`)
              ELSE TIME_TO_SEC(`Time`)
         END AS tsecs
  FROM timesheet
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @mn := 0, @en := 0, @dt := '', @rn := 0) init
  ORDER BY Date, Time
) t
GROUP BY MachineNo, Empcardno, Date
```

how to convert this query to make compatible with ms access pdo connection using php

Comment: Use IIf() instead of CASE. Use [ ] instead of apostrophes to delimit field names. Also remove CROSS JOIN keywords. The dataset will be a Cartesian product. Will probably need PARAMETERS clause (I've never used because I avoid dynamic parameterized queries). Roughly, syntax like: `SELECT … FROM (SELECT IIf(...) AS rn, IIf(...) AS tsecs FROM timesheet, (SELECT ...) AS init) AS t GROUP BY …`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a query that will give you the same results on Access. It uses a different approach to generating row numbers, using a self `LEFT JOIN` on a lower time and counting how many records there are with a lower time. Since Access already stores times as fractions of a day, the `SUM` can be simplified and we use [`FORMAT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/format-a-date-and-time-field-47fbbdc1-52fa-416a-b8d5-ba24d881b698) to convert the time to `HH:MM:SS` format:

```
SELECT MachineNo, Empcardno, [Date], 
       FORMAT(SUM(IIF(rn MOD 2 = 0, -TimeValue([Time]), TimeValue([Time]))),'hh:nn:ss') AS total_time
FROM (
  SELECT t1.MachineNo, t1.Empcardno, t1.Date, t1.Time, COUNT(t2.MachineNo) AS rn
  FROM timesheet t1
  LEFT JOIN timesheet t2 ON t2.MachineNo = t1.MachineNo 
                        AND t2.Empcardno = t1.Empcardno
                        AND t2.Date = t1.Date
                        AND TimeValue(t2.Time) < TimeValue(t1.Time)
  GROUP BY t1.MachineNo, t1.Empcardno, t1.Date, t1.Time
)  AS t
GROUP BY MachineNo, Empcardno, Date
```

Output:

```
MachineNo   Empcardno   Date        total_time
1           5           21/05/2020  08:19:12
1           5           22/05/2020  08:28:42
```

Comment: this query dose not work in pdo it's show me an error **Execute query error, because: Array ( [0] => 07002 [1] => -3010 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1. (SQLExecute[-3010] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:258) [3] => 07002 )**

Comment: @HiteshTripathi without seeing your PHP PDO code I can't tell you what is causing that problem. I have tested this query in MS Access on my own machine with your sample data from the previous question and it works as described.

Comment: pdo connection is fine it show me result for simple select query for this table.but i dont know what goes wrong for above query

Comment: try{
    $accConn = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=$db", $username, $password);
 }catch(PDOException $e){
     echo $e->getMessage();
 }
$accstmt = $accConn->query($sql);

Comment: @HiteshTripathi I think the quotes around `hh:nn:ss` need to be single quotes, not double. See my edit

Comment: i tested with both types of quotes but same result.i also check for field name and table name  they are ok

Comment: @HiteshTripathi you might need `[]` around `Time` and `Date`. See my edit.

Comment: problem with data type of the time field it is stored as text in access db therefor this query is not working

Comment: Are you still getting the error, or just the wrong results?

Comment: @HiteshTripathi see my edit, that will resolve issues with `Time` being a text field. But you really should change it to a `Time`...

Comment: I am unable to change its type because this db is filled by embedded machine.

Comment: @HiteshTripathi that's fair enough. Anyway, I'm glad we've got it working.